# Compute the addition table of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Compute the addition table of a field with $8$ elements. Hint: Factor $x^8-x$ over $\mathbb{Z_2}$.

In the previous theorem, the book shows a proof of the existence of a field having $p^n$ elements by using the smallest field over which $x^q-x$ splits, which is what it is hinting at.

What I did is to add the seven roots of unity $\zeta=e^{i2\pi/7}$ to $\mathbb Z_2$. However, to fully express the table, I need to know what element corresponds to the expression $1+\zeta$, and then all follows, but I can't compute it.

Comment: My approach would be to just find an irreducible cubic $p$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$, and then use that $\mathbb{F}_8 \simeq \mathbb{F}_2[x] / (p(x))$.

Comment: Indeed, @DanielSchepler, the question demands an additive answer, while the method of adjoining seventh roots of unity is basically multiplicative. Personally, I think the πhint” was inapposite.

Comment: Of course, if you use my hint, then it's actually the multiplication table that becomes more interesting, rather than the addition table.  That said, I think $x^8 - x = x^8 + x$ factors as $x (x+1) (x^3 + x + 1) (x^3 + x^2 + 1)$; so some of the extension elements satisfy $\zeta^3 = \zeta + 1$ while others satisfy $\zeta^3 = \zeta^2 + 1$.

Comment: @Boots I think you need an $x^3$ there, or else you just wind up with $\Bbb F_4$.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake. If we take the example like others have mentioned where $p(x) = x^3 + x + 1$ we can use $K = \mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]/<x^3 + x + 1>$ as a model for $\mathbb{F}_{8}$. Now what are the elements of $K$? $K$ is all polynomials of the form $ax^2 + bx + c$ such that $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}$, so we get a set like:

$\{0,1,x,x+1,x^2,x^2 + x, x^2 + 1, x^2 + x + 1\}$. To make the addition table we can simply consider the additions of the polynomials of this set.

Comment: If you want to use complex seventh roots of unity, you need to construct the field $\Bbb{F}_8$ as $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]/\mathfrak{p}$, where the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ can be either $\langle 2,\zeta^3+\zeta+1\rangle$ or $\langle 2,\zeta^3+\zeta^2+1\rangle$. The choice of prime ideal is up to you. Both choices lead to isomorphic quotient fields. An isomorphism takes the coset of $\zeta$ to that of its complex conjugate. Mind you, I would also construct this field the same way Daniel Schepler did. Thinking in terms of complex numbers is just extra baggage to lug around here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you will have an easier time using Daniel Schepler's hint:

Let $p(x) = x^3 + x + 1 \in \Bbb Z_2[x]$, with $u$ a root. I leave it to you to show this is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_2$.

Clearly, $u^3 = u+1$. The powers of $u$ are:

$u^2$ (we cannot reduce this further),

$u^3 = u+1$, $u^4 = u(u^3) = u(u+1) = u^2 + u$ (again, this cannot be further reduced).

$u^5 = u^2(u^3) = u^2(u+1) = u^3 + u^2 = u^2 + u + 1$,

$u^6 = (u^3)^2 = (u+1)^2 = u^2+1$,

and, of course, $u^7 = u(u^6) = u(u^2+1) = u^3 + u = (u+1) + u = 1$.

The problem with your approach straight off the bat is: "What is $\zeta$ ?", since the expression $e^{i2\pi/7}$ makes no sense over the field $\Bbb Z_2$.

Clearly, $\Bbb Z_2(u) \cong \Bbb Z_2[x]/(p(x))$ is a field of eight elements. Addition is straight-forward, as we have:

$\Bbb Z_2(u) = \{a_0 + a_1u + a_2u^2\mid a_0,a_1,a_2 \in \Bbb Z_2\} \cong (\Bbb Z_2)^3$ as a $\Bbb Z_2$ vector-space.

Comment: Yes this is a good answer, the idea is that the field will be generated by the roots of $f(x) = x^{p^{n}} - x$, which in this case is $f(x) = x^{8} - x$. Furthermore, it is the splitting field of $f(x)$ over its prime subfield.

Comment: Well after factorising $x^8-x$, we get $x(x-1)(x^6+x^5+...+x+1)$ so in essence I was adjoining a root of the latter?

Comment: Not quite, because $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=(x^3+x^2+1)(x^3+x+1)$.